# How to increment row value in an index function in excel?

Tags: excel, indexing

[image: IMAGE LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0rEK.png]

In the image I show the dataset. Basically, I want to copy each nation's GDP from (F:27-F:40) into row 5, but I am cannot simply drag the formula horizontal. How should I do this? Keep in mind I do not want to simply copy and paste because I want a formula so I can alter the data later if need be.

Comment: If the order remains the same, then use TRANSPOSE.

Comment: Thank you Ben. But even with Tranpose, how do I make it so the column (F) stays constant, but only the row number changes?

Comment: `=TRANSPOSE(F27:F40)`. Select the entire range in row 5, enter the formula, and then confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. This assumes that you are not working with Office 365, at which point you would not need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX($F$27:$F$40,COLUMN(A$1))
```

It will automatically increase row number when you drag and across right.

If country name is same to both place then you can use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination.

```
=INDEX($F$27:$F$40,MATCH(B$1,$B$27:$B$40,0))
```

[image]